# Kompose creates many files from one compose file?

Tags: kubernetes, kompose

I'm in the process of trying to convert a Docker Cloud based setup to k8s.

I've found the k8s kompose tool which can convert a docker compose file into a k8s file. Based on my results I'm wondering if it is possible to define a full stack in a single file.

I'm running `kompose convert` but it ends up creating several different files:

[image]

Next I'm wanting to upload my stack to k8s via the UI:

[image]

Is the only way, to upload each of the files that was generated separately? Or is it possible to create a single file to represent the stack like with compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure via the UI but via the command line Kompose gives you the ability to "up" them all as you are used to with docker-compose. I believe Kompose also has support for Healm which might be your easiest route for utilizing all the files in an easy-ish way.

Comment: Thanks, I installed it on the production machine, ssh'd in and ran `kompose up` seems to be working.